# Why am I getting 404 when setting up Angular App with Nginx

Tags: angular, nginx, http-status-code-404

I am trying to setup an angular app with nginx. Here is my nginx conf file:

```
server {
listen              4300;
server_name         localhost;


location / {
    root /root/sultana/thumbs;
    try_files $uri no-img.png;
}
location /dashboard {
    root /srv/www/htdocs;
    index index.html index.htm;
}
}
```

The first location serves only images and works as expected. The request are forwarded by HAProxy. When I navigate to /dashboardLogin I get 404.

Comment: what is  `/dashboardLogin`.  It is not defined anywhere.  I guess it should be `/dashboard/login`

Comment: @jcuypers /dashboardLogin is the root path (default) path for my angular application; but i will try what you suggested